# How I can receive output of a Linux command run in the foreground "command &" " [number of process in foreground] [PID]" in a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to redirect the output of the command `firefox &`. I know that adding "&" means that we will run the command in foreground and when we use it we receive **"[number of process in foreground] [PID]"**.
This is what I have done:

```
firefox & > firefoxFile
```

But when I opened file *firefoxFile* I found it empty. I didn't find the **"[number of process in foreground] [PID]"**.

Comment: What's *forground* and how is its number any different than its PID? Maybe you should try rewording your question to make it clearer

Comment: i mean foreground

Comment: Solution: firefox > firefoxFile &
& place command to the background not to the foreground.

Comment: BTW, this question would be better asked at our sister site [unix.se]; SO is only for questions about *developing software*.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the job control metadata? That's not part of a program's *output* at all, and scripts turn job control off anyhow. Use `$!` to capture the PID. There is no job number in environments without job control.

Comment: i want to redirect the output of ``` firefox & ``` to a file ,that means that i should when i use ```cat firefoxFile``` , will find this message [number of process in background] [PID]

Comment: That *isn't* output of `firefox &` at all. It's output **of your shell**.

Comment: Anyhow, what's your real goal? To get the PID? There are better ways to do it.

Comment: i want to run firefox in background and redirect his informations (PID and tache number ) to a file : "firefoxFile"

Comment: Once again, **the job number is not guaranteed to exist at all**. It's a bad idea to try to redirect it, because only shells with job control (which is turned off in scripts) will even have one.

Comment: Just `echo "$!" >file` to write the PID.

Comment: when i write ``` firefox &``` in the terminal, i make the command run in the background and receive that message [1] [PID] what i should to do if i want redirect that message [1] [PID] to a file ?that's my question ,i try firefox > firefoxFile & but when i use cat firefoxFile i find it empty i don't found "[1] [PID]" message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is a command separator, just like `;` is (but with the side effect of putting the command before it in the background, and the difference that not having another command after it is not an error). Everything after it is a separate command.

Thus, redirections must come *before* the `&`.

Thus, for your example:

```
firefox > firefoxFile &
```

Comment: that what i have do ```firefox > firefoxFile &```
but when i use ```cat firefoxFile``` i don't find anything the file is empty

Comment: That's correct, expected and normal behavior. The file will only contain output if `firefox` writes output to stdout. The PID and job number are not output from firefox.

Comment: when i write ``` firefox &``` in the terminal, i make the command run in the background and receive that message [1] [PID] what i should to do if i want redirect that message [1] [PID] to a file ?that's my question ,i try ```firefox > firefoxFile &``` but when i use ```cat firefoxFile``` i find it empty i don't found "[1] [PID]" message

Comment: `{ firefox & } 2> outfile` -- but that works only in the terminal, not in scripts, and questions about interactive/terminal use belong on [Unix.se], not here.